# RegexReplace Google Sheets - Quotations in text - Removing title and alt from Image html

Tags: html, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to update image alt attributes and titles in Google Sheets. I've had the client approve the updates and was hoping to insert the old image html into a cell and have it automatically update the title's and alt descriptions, leaving everything else the same.

I'm having trouble dealing with quotations in Google sheets. I need to search within the string for `alt="image.url` and `title="image.url"`and extract it. Ideally I would be able to directly replace the title and alt description within the cell, but if that's an issue I can do that in another step. I just need to successfully remove the original alt and title.

- there is no set order or guarantee that the images will have both a title or an alt description (or either)
- I have the updated descriptions/titles in separate cells within that sheet
- I've used REGEXREPLACE before, what I seem to be having trouble with is the quotations "
- I used this logic in a tester (alt description only) and it worked correctly but it doesn't work in Sheets: `(^.+)(alt="[^"]*")(.+)`

Example image code (alt description only):
`<img class="lazy-image-load loaded" data-src="https://media.site.com/exampleimage.jpg" border="0" alt="townhomes" src="https://media.site.com/exampleimage.jpg" data-was-processed="true">`

Example (title & alt description)
`<img class="lazy-image-load loaded" data-src="https://media.site.com/exampleimage.jpg" border="0" alt="townhomes" title="Nice Home" src="https://media.site.com/exampleimage.jpg" data-was-processed="true">`

Example (NO title or alt description)
`<img class="lazy-image-load loaded" data-src="https://media.site.com/exampleimage.jpg" border="0" src="https://media.site.com/exampleimage.jpg" data-was-processed="true">`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm kind of at the point where I'm wondering if this is even worth it.

Comment: What do you need it replaced with, in other words, how would your desired result look like? Care to share your spreadsheet?

Comment: Btw, the double quotes mean end of string in GS so you might want to try using something like: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,SUBSTITUTE("(^.+)(alt=|[^|]*|)(.+)","|",""""),"$1YourValue$3")`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Since GS interpret the double quotes as end of string you will have to define a double quote in a string with this symbol: `""""`.

Your formula should therefore be like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,SUBSTITUTE("(^.+)(alt=|[^|]*|)(.+)","|",""""),"$1YourValue$3")
```

### Reference

[Double quotes in GS](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/23314295?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm confused by what the vertical lines represent here? Also, what if I wanted to remove title tags? Could this be done if I didn't know whether it would appear before or after the alt tag? I tried adding to your code by putting `(title=|[^|]*|)`, didn't work.